# How to attach an .mdf file to an Amazon RDS instance?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just created an instance of SQL Server Express in Amazon RDS since I want to perform a test but I need to add a sample database "AdventureWorksLT2012_Data" that is in extension .mdf.

I got to connect to the database without problems through MSSMS but when I try to attach the BD that I have locally I can not do it

[image]

And I tried to investigate in the AWS documentation the way to attach this type of files to the instance of my BD but I can not calculate any reference.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to add the .mdf file to the RDS cloud but when I tried to add it to the database instance using the following command:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
        @restore_db_name='AdventureWorksLT', 
       @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::sqlserverp/Andveruteworks.mdf';
```

I got the following error

```
 [2017-11-22 20:40:22.247] The media family on device '0FEAAE12-E9A1-4D84-8AEF-39AD0FFB496A' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family. [2017-11-22 20:40:22.250] RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally. [2017-11-22 20:40:22.267] Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent RESTORE_DB request. [2017-11-22 20:40:22.373] Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
```

The only thing that I want to do was to use a backup of the database (.bak) which I uploaded to the S3 AWS service and later guiding me on the following documentation

[enter link description here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html)

and using the following stored procedures I managed to attach the BD to the instance of my sql server

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
        @restore_db_name='AdventureWorksLT', 
        @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::sqlserverp/AdventureWorks2012-FullDatabaseBackup.bak';

exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status
```

[image]